# How to encode HTML using javascript Except some tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to encode the html tags as a string except some tags like anchor tag using javascript
something similar to php's function "htmlspecialchar"

Note: I never wants to stripe the html tags.

Suppose my html string is like

```
<div><span>test string</span>div content goes here <a herf="xyz.com">My Portal</a></div>
```

Expected output should be

```
<div><span>test string</span>div content goes here My Portal </div>
```

Here "My portal should" turns to hyperlink instead of getting encoded. but rest all other tags are get encoded and should be displayed on view as string

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. `<a href="example.com">My Portal</a>` is already the right code to turn "My Portal" into a link.

Comment: is this html creating dynamically ?

Comment: @ansari-khalid What you want to do? Your href code is already fine.